# Error #35584 when trying to run Minetest with flatpak

Tags: raspbian, software-installation

I'm trying to install minetest on my Raspberry Pi B+ by running

```
flatpak install net.minetest.Minetest
```

I got it installed but after rebooting my pi it doesn't show up anywhere and  trying to open it with

```
flatpak run net.minetest.Minetest
```

returns

```
Note that the directory

'/root/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share'

is not in the search path set by the XDG_DATA_DIRS environment variable, so applications installed by Flatpak may not appear on your desktop until the session is restarted

error: ldconfig failed, exit status 35584
```

I have no idea what this means or how to resolve it.

Thanks for your help!